# How to indicate in Django that a recently created data is new for a period of time?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, time

I want to create an app that when you give a list of, for example, string data, where it has to make every letter uppercase. For a duration of 5 minutes to indicate that that string is new in the database. After 5 minutes to indicate that the string is processed.

Any tips on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method *is_new_in_database* to your model that checks if the object is newly created:

```
class YourModelName(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    def is_new_in_database(self):
        return (self.creation_date - timezone.now()) >= datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```